# TradingView/PineScript: How to reference the last label for trade entries?

Tags: pine-script, tradingview-api

Although my code references entry and close if a certain pattern is generated, the trade is taking place randomly.

My strategy has an alternative timeframe of 60 minutes on a 1 minute candle.

I figured that if the previous pattern was bearish, it would keep on generating sell order even if the pattern was no longer void (and was far far away, even 10 timeframes away). Same for bullish.

My problem would be solved if I can reference the last label and make sure that it generated at the end of the previous timeframe (or beginning of the current).

But there seems to be no way to do so. The best possible solution I could come up with is use "valuewhen" and make sure that it is between +/-.2% horizon. But this would still generate entries anywhere on the chart (and not on the current timeframe).

Is there a workaround to it?

P.S. Please note that this is only happening in real-time. On chart, the strategy is generating trades accurately. The strategy involves simple harmonic patterns traded through fib levels.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Hi Gu5tavo! Thanks for the comment. Apparently, I figured it out. So, using barssince(valid condition) and then confirming that it was less than the timeframe solved it. Thanks a lot, buddy!

Answer (score 0):

Solved it!

If we use the **barssince function**, and ensure that our valid condition occurred within the timeframe (using a conditional operator), it serves the purpose.

```
confirmed_trade = (barssince(valid_condition)<=alt_time) or (barssince(another_valid_condition)<=alt_time)
```

This will return a boolean, which can then be used as an additional condition for the entry (buy/sell).

P.S. I know I've inserted an extra parenthesis, but that's how I'm using it. My code runs into errors for reasons unknown. Currently, I'm running it on version 2 (that's the only version that runs my code without tearing it apart). For version 5, you'll need the **ta.barssince**. Thanks!